# Mac Terminal Sending Email With Attachment

Tags: macos, bash, email, terminal

I'm trying to make a bash script that will send an email to all contacts which will contain a message and an attachment. This is not for malicious purposes.

How could I do this? Is this possible? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where are "all contacts" stored for you? Is this the contacts in your address book application? Have you considered using apple script for this?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I have previously used uuencode to accomplish this:

```
uuencode source.txt destination.txt | mail -s "subject of mail" youremail@yourdomain.com
```

You can use this in your bash script. Sample:

```
uuencode /usr/bin/xxx.c MyFile.c | mail -s "mailing my c file" youremail@yourdomain.com
```

http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/pseries/v5r3/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.aix.cmds/doc/aixcmds5/uuencode.htm

Comment: What would I replace file.txt with? ~/Path/To/file.txt? Why are there two?

Comment: sorry for the short reply...first argument to uuencode is source and second argument is the destination file name....so if you do like:      uuencode source.txt destination.txt | mail -s "subject" youremail@yourdomain.com               this will send your source.txt from local system to your email id with name file.txt

Comment: Thanks.
Also, how would I make it so that it sends an email to everyone on my contact list?

Comment: For that I think first you need to import all your contacts in your bash script and then send attachment via this command. mail command is the command which is responsible to send mails, i am not aware of a way to send to all in your contact list. Need to research a bit ;)

Comment: Can I attached 2 or more files?

Comment: Not working for me on MacOS Big Sur. I expected an empty emali with an attachment, but I receive an empty email with no attachments. I tried attaching a .jpg or a .txt

Answer (score 3):

You might also use AppleScript:

```
tell application "Mail"
    tell (make new outgoing message)
        set subject to "subject"
        set content to "content"
        -- set visible to true
        make new to recipient at end of to recipients with properties {address:"name@example.com", name:"Name"}
        make new attachment with properties {file name:(POSIX file "/tmp/test.txt")} at after the last paragraph
        send
    end tell
end tell
```

You can use an explicit run handler to pass arguments from a shell:

```
osascript -e 'on run {a}
    set text item delimiters to ";"
    repeat with l in paragraphs of a
        set {contact, address} to text items of l
    end repeat
end run' "Name1;name1@example.com
Name2;name2@example.com"
```